# Swapping lines in a text

Tags: python, linux, line, swap

How to change this:

```
fv (x,y,z) begin  print x;;;  print y ;;; return x + y + z end;

x = fv(2,34,5)

g (x) begin y = x + 45 ;;;  return y end;

z = g(23)

r = 53

h (x,y,z,r) begin  print x;;;  print y ;;; print z;;;print r;;;return x + y + z end;
```

To this:

```
def fv (x,y,z) :    
    print x   
    print y   
    return x + y + z 

x = fv(2,34,5)

def g (x) :  
    y = x + 45  
    return y 

z = g(23)

r = 53

def h (x,y,z,r) :   
    print x   
    print y   
    print z   
    print r   
    return x + y + z
```

I'm not asking for a full code or to do my homework, I only need advices and/or samples or a direction how to do this.

Comment: Are you just trying to reformat your code? You may want to take a look at `replace()`, `split()`, and possibly regular expressions.

Comment: I read the first code from an input.txt, and the second must be the output to a txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could get you started

```
for line in code:
    line = line.replace( "begin", " :\n" + " " * 4 ).replace( ";;;", "\n" + " " * 4 ).replace( "end;", "\n" + " " * 4 )
```

Comment: There remains the problem of inserting "def " in front of the functions. I would run a second pass on the output here and check every line to see if it has ':' in it. If so, then insert "def " at the front of the line.

Comment: @erapert yes good catch. It also does a poor job of indenting properly . I just meant to get him started.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're only looking for a starting hint, and this is probably homework...

Do a replace() on the various line-enders (e.g. "begin", ";;;", "end;") converting them to "\n", with possibly a ':' in one of them.

Split the resulting text into lines with .split("\n")

Walk the lines to adjust the line prefixes ("def ", indentation)

Put the lines back together using "\n".join(...)

Write the output text

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `sed` command line tool, for instance. It's a bit hard to know what tools you're expected/allowed to use ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters you `open()` the file, use its `readlines()` method to get it into a list of strings.

From there you could iterate through that list and use a combination of `split(";;;")` methods or something more complex from the `re` module on strings.

Comment: Looking positions of ';;;' with respect to surrounding whitespace -- I think he's probably going to need `re` to get the indentation correct (if that matters).  `re.sub` would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but take a look at the Ply parser project.  You will have to learn about regular expressions and Backus Naur formatting.

[Ply parser](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)